# TestNG: How will you run your test(@Test) 10 time with multiple data set without @DataProvider?

Tags: testng

This question has been asked last week in an interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of getting this done.

- **Approach #1** - Use a factory method to produce multiple instances of a test class that contains just one `@Test` method.

The below sample shows how it would look like:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RunManyTimes {
  private int data;

  public RunManyTimes(int data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    System.err.println("Running with data " + data);
  }

  @Factory
  public static Object[] getData() {
    List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach(value -> data.add(new RunManyTimes(value)));
    return data.toArray(new Object[0]);
  }
}
```

Here's the output

```
Running with data 3
Running with data 9
Running with data 4
Running with data 7
Running with data 2
Running with data 5
Running with data 1
Running with data 8
Running with data 6
Running with data 10

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 10, Passes: 10, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

- **Approach #2** - You add a suite level parameter which is comma separated and represents the range of values that would be used to execute your tests. Have them parsed in an implementation of `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener` and which creates multiple `<test>` tags each of which contain the same class but with a different value as the method parameter.

Here's a sample:

Test class looks like below:

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DynamicallyConstructedParameter {

  @Test
  @Parameters("data")
  public void testMethod(int data) {
    System.err.println("Parameter passed was " + data);
  }
}
```

The listener looks like below:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class ParameterInjectingListener implements IAlterSuiteListener {

  @Override
  public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
    XmlSuite xmlSuite = suites.get(0);
    List<Integer> datum = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] parameters = xmlSuite.getParameter("parameters").split(",");
    for (String parameter : parameters) {
      datum.add(Integer.parseInt(parameter.trim()));
    }

    datum.forEach(
        value -> {
          XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
          xmlTest.setName("dynamic_test_" + value);
          XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass(DynamicallyConstructedParameter.class);
          xmlClass.getLocalParameters().put("data", Integer.toString(value));
          xmlTest.getXmlClasses().add(xmlClass);
        });
  }
}
```

Suite xml looks like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="54150271_suite" parallel="false" verbose="2" configfailurepolicy="continue">
  <listeners>
    <listener
      class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn54150271.ParameterInjectingListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <parameter name="parameters" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"/>
</suite>
```

Here's the output:

```
...
... TestNG 7.0.0-beta3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
Parameter passed was 1
PASSED: testMethod(1)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_1
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Parameter passed was 2
PASSED: testMethod(2)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_2
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
PASSED: testMethod(3)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_3
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Parameter passed was 3
Parameter passed was 4
Parameter passed was 5
PASSED: testMethod(4)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_4
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
PASSED: testMethod(5)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_5
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
Parameter passed was 6
PASSED: testMethod(6)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_6
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
Parameter passed was 7
PASSED: testMethod(7)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_7
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
Parameter passed was 8
Parameter passed was 9
PASSED: testMethod(8)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_8
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
PASSED: testMethod(9)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_9
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
PASSED: testMethod(10)

===============================================
    dynamic_test_10
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
Parameter passed was 10

===============================================
54150271_suite
Total tests run: 10, Passes: 10, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```